# Assign string to label Object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to assign a String to Label but i Cannot able assign to a Label Field

i have Attached my code with it

```
if (intAdditionalTestId == 16 || intAdditionalTestId == 24)
{                                
    strControlName = "lblMGOSSC" + Convert.ToString(intAdditionalTestId).PadLeft(2, '0') + "01AddUpd";
    DisplayMessage(strControlName.ToString().Trim());
    lblField = (Label)Page.FindControl(strControlName);

    if (lblField.Text.Contains("[ADD]"))
    {
        intUpdateFlag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        intUpdateFlag = 1;
    }
```

I want to store the value of `strControlName` to `lblField`

Error Message Displayed While Running the Code:

> Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.

Comment: You want to assign string to object? I guess, `lblField` is WPF's `Label`.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no code that shows _I want to store the value of strControlName to lblField_

Comment: You should provide your error message other vice I'll put a close vote for *why this code is not working*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find label using a string which you want to set to as label text. It is wrong.

You should change it;

```
lblField = (Label)Page.FindControl(strControlName);
```

to

```
lblField = (Label)Page.FindControl("lblField");//"ldlField" is ID of label"
lblField.Text = strControlName;
```